# Why docker is not working with this config in iptables?

Tags: iptables, docker

i have installed docker but standard policy is all open.
I added this rules in iptables

```
 -N DOCKER-USER
 -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 80  -j ACCEPT
 -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
 -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
```

but the result is

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80      
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I have the same issue.  as soon I started changng the `DOCKER-USER` chain, docker stopped adding it to the `FORWARD` chain and I can't figure out how to make docker use it again.

Comment: for whatever reason, docker isn't creating the `DOCKER-USER` chain until i reboot

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to create `DOCKER-USER`.  It should already exist, and the `FORWARD` chain should use it.  I have found that you need to stop all running containers and restart docker to make it appear.